# getComputedTextLength throws an error in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, d3.js

I'm writing a unit test that uses getComputedTextLength() and test passes in all browsers except IE (i'm using IE10).

Any ideas?

This is the error im getting: `Unexpected call to method or property access.`

Answer (score 3):

You could fallback to calling getBBox() and look at the width field of the result for IE10. It isn't quite the same but it's better than nothing I guess.

Comment: Yea... it's not the same :) but it does the trick. It would be nice to find out why IE is freaking out about getComputedTextLength()

Answer (score 3):

This occurs when the element is not in the visible DOM. You can do a check before hand to avoid having to use try/catch.

```js
if(!document.body.contains(self.node())) return;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my limited investigations it seems IE11 (so I assume IE10) throws this error when the actual element is not visible. To get around this problem I did

```
var a;
try{
     a=textElement_.getComputedTextLength();
}catch(e){
    a=textElement_.childNodes[0].length*8; //I used 8 as a width, but you should experiment
}
```

I hope this helps. Once the element is visible it seems to use getComputedTextLength normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you call "el.getSubStringLength()" in a SVG in an iframe. Then you refresh this iframe, IE will also complain about this, but refreshing the whole page will work just fine.

I guess this was because the text element is already in the DOM, and there is a bug between these update worker.